# RegEx to delete all double whitespace EXCEPT \n? preg_replace

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have imported a plain-text version of PDF using a Python script, but it has a bunch of garbage artifacts that I just don't care about.

The only whitespace I care about is (1) **single** spaces, and (2) **double** \n's.

**Single space,** for obvious reasons, between word boundaries. **Double \n's,** to demarcate between paragraphs.

The *garbage* whitespace it contains looks like this:

```
[\ \n\t]+ all jumbled together
```

Which leads me to another problem, sometimes the paragraphs are demarcated by

```
[\n][\s]+[\n]
```

I am not experienced enough with regex to make it ignore the inner whitespace between the two `\n`'s. As an amateur RegExer, my problem is that `\s` includes `\n`.

If it didn't -- I think this would be a really easy problem to solve.

All other white space is irrelevant, and nothing I am trying is working really whatsoever.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

### Sample text

```
Summary: The Department of Environment in Bangladesh seized 265 sacks of poultry feed 
tainted with tannery waste and various chemicals. 

Synthesis/Analysis: The Department of Environment seized the tainted poultry feed on 
28 March from a house in the city of Adabar located in Dhaka province. Workers were 
found in the house, which was used as an illegal factory, producing the tainted feed. The 
Bangladesh Environment Conservation Act allowed for a case to be filed against the 
factory’s manager, Mahmud Hossain, and the owner, who was not named. 

It was reported that the Department of Environment had also closed three other factories 
in Hazaribag a month prior to this instance for the same charges. The Bangladesh Council of 
Scientific and Industrial Research found that samples from the feed taken from these 
factories had “dangerous levels of chromium…”  The news report also stated that “poultry 
6 



and eggs became poisonous” from consuming the tainted feed, which would also cause 
health concerns for consumers.
```

---

This is just leading me to more fixes... Gotta remove all the page numbers, and random double \n's.

Comment: Look at the number of regex questions you have asked.  Do you think it could be worth your time (and ours) if you started getting serious about learning them?  It isn't that hard if you read the OReilly Regex book carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mike. I'm glad RegEx is easy for you.

Comment: Mike's comment was right. If you have to ask that many questions, perhaps you should study the subject instead of continuing to ask people to do things for you. I like The Regex Cookbook, myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an assertion to make `\s` exclude line breaks:

```
 ((?!\n)\s){2,}
```

To merge linebreaks with `\n\s+\n` spaces in between, you can use a similar construct in place of the `\s+`. But for simplicity I would just use two `preg_match`es and first merge linebreaks, then clean up double spaces.

Comment: I have never heard of this assertion, I am Googling it now for more explanations on it!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html has a understandable introduction on lookahead and behind assertions and the ?! negative variants.

Comment: This is what I wound up using `$find[5]='/[\s]*((?!\n)\s){2,}[\s]*/'; $fix[5]='<br/><br/>';`

Comment: @mario how can the same be done, but to protect whitespace within `<pre>` tags?

Comment: @Lea: Separate those areas beforehand.

Comment: @mario thanks, I achieved this by using a callback that matches `<pre..>..</pre>` or whitespace and then only perform actual replacement when matched string is whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

1. Replace "\s*\n\s*\n\s*" with "\n\n".

   This will standardise the paragraph separators.
2. Replace "\s* \s*" with " ".

   This will standardise the word separators.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/(\h)+/$1/g;
s/\n(\s*\n)+/\n\n/g;
```

The above will delete horizontal whitespace (I assume you are not worried about vertical tab or carriage return) and all newlines over double-space.

Answer (score 0):

Ever so slightly hacky, but I think this should do the trick:

`preg_replace('/\t|( ){2,}|(\n)\s+(\n)/', '\1\2\3', $data);`

Bonus: doesn't require doing two passes on the string.

Comment: The \1\2\3 is just a trick for replacing the right part of the string. Any chance you could upload some test data? Difficult to get it right without being able to try it properly

Comment: Sure... It's a gargantuan file... So I will just post a little bit of it

Comment: I think Stack Overflow is cleaning up the file as well, when I am posting it. Haha